# python replace linebreaks with string while reading from file

Tags: python, string

I have a file named "test.txt" which contains the below content:
hello
hi
bye for now

I am using the below code to replace the linebreaks with comma (,) in the file:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as data:
    for each_line in data:
        try:
            name = each_line.replace("\n", ",").strip()
            print(name)

        except ValueError:
            pass
```

**This shows the result:**

```
hello,
hi,
bye for now
```

**But my desired result should be:**

```
hello,hi,bye for now
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: `print(name, end='')` (And don't forget to `flush` at the end)

Comment: `str = str.__add__(name)`